# Experiences with the various ways of running svnserve on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, svnserve

Is there anyone out there that can share experiences with the various flavours of running svnserve on Windows. I'm using it mainly for a small hobby project that I share with friends, so it will run on my desktop.

Using the Collabnet Subversion Edge seems a bit heavy weight. Any drawbacks in just run 'svnserve'? I recently found VisualSVNserver which seems to add some easy administrative functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good experience with VisualSVN server, very easy to set up and configure user accounts.
It is also very easy to upgrade, just run the latest installer and you're done.

With VisualSVN you can run HTTPS with a self signed certificate. If you just run svnserve you're left without encryption and that is not recommended if you plan to access your server from the internet.

Keep in mind that whatever solution you choose they all use standard svn as the backend and you can easily move your repositories from one solution to another.

If you plan to make your project open source you can host your code at sourceforge or codeplex.